# Common features: the eyes, the smile, or the (a?) pug nose.

Tags: articles

A quote from a [lang-8](http://lang-8.com/) entry, describing a Russian web-project:

> Upload your photo and find an orphan who looks like you. The goal of our project is to show you that there may be a kid in an orphanage who has facial features similar to yours. For example, the eyes, the smile, or **the** pug nose.

Shouldn't it be

> , or **a** pug nose.

since the authors of the text cannot be sure that you have a pug nose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all *examples*. It does not assume you have all the characteristics mentioned. Sure, everyone has eyes, and everyone has a smile, but not everyone has a pug nose. Author is trying to be a little bit cute/funny here; he might as well have said "blue eyes" or "crooked smile" as more specific examples, and it still would not be claiming that you have any such characteristic.

Comment: Thanks, Brian! So "**the** pug nose" is okay?

Comment: Yeah.  "...the pug nose" is okay.

Comment: Yes, this is what I suspected; +1.